# How to block rotation in ios 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, rotation

I used this code to block the rotation before ios 7 (i was also using xibs, now storyboard)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
  return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
 return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

now that i migrated to storyboard and ios7 it is not working, my view is still rotating.

UPDATE:
I solved this by adding this code to the delegate, now my previous code works like charm

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
 NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
 if (self.fullScreenVideoIsPlaying) {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
 }
 else {        
     if(self.window.rootViewController){
         UIViewController *presentedViewController = [[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
         orientations = [presentedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
 }


return orientations;
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Atrik's code worked. Here is a more complete solution which allows locking and unlocking of portrait-mode-only even with the use of UINavigationController

```
appdelegate .h


@property (nonatomic) BOOL screenIsPortraitOnly;


appdelegate .m

#pragma mark - View Orientation

- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    if (self.screenIsPortraitOnly) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    else {
        if(self.window.rootViewController){
            UIViewController *presentedViewController = [[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
            orientations = [presentedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
        }
        return orientations;
    }
}
```

For all view controllers where I need Portrait Lock
If you haven't used a subclass which has the app delegate imported then don't forget to import the delegate. For most view controllers I use a subclass of UIViewController which at least does importation.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

I use this for all portrait locked viewcontrollers.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:true];
    [self portraitLock];
}

-(void) portraitLock {
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.screenIsPortraitOnly = true;
}

#pragma mark - interface posiiton

- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

ViewDidLoad runs before viewDidAppear so I run this in my subclass of UIViewController to unlock all screens. The viewWillAppear with the  lock method is used only in the cotrollers which I need to lock the screen.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self portraitUnLock];
}

-(void) portraitUnLock {
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.screenIsPortraitOnly = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want in landscape mode then you can do it with xcode project setting
go to Target > summary > support interface orientations

[image]

Or you can do a code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In XCode 5, which is required to be used for iOS7 development, you can go to your target and under Deployment Info uncheck everything except Portrait for device orientation.

[image: portrait only]

Comment: I am unable to do this. When I click Landscape Left, the checkbox turns off then back on immediately. Also, if I go to the Info.plist and remove the landscape orientations, it puts them back.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your app to rotate at all (no matter which view is active), you can click on your project in the Xcode sidebar, scroll down, and deselect Landscape Left and Landscape Right.

[image]